# JSON object changes when sending multiple values

Tags: json, ajax

I have a number of objects I want to send to the server as a JSON object.

Here is what I have:

This object is a dictionary of values and keys.

```
var param = new Object();

        // q1
        param['queryParams[0].Key'] = 'q1';
        param['queryParams[0].Value'] = $("select#q1dd").val();

        // q2
        param['queryParams[1].Key'] = 'q2';
        param['queryParams[1].Value'] = $("select#q2dd").val();
```

When i send this object over to the server by itself, it works perectly fine with this code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: $.url("/MailListGenerator/GetMailListQueries"),
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: param
    });
}
```

The JSON objects looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsXwU.png)

However, when I wrap it to include multiple objects, such as this code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: $.url("/MailListGenerator/GetMailListQueries"),
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: { queryParam: JSON.stringify(param), queryName: name }
    });
}
```

The "param" objects gets converted into something weird which I cant end up using, it turns into
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uliBT.png)

The reason why I use JSON.Stringify is because otherwise the objects becomes even more weird.

How can I send the "param" object as a Dictionary whilst also sending multiple objects?